# Firestore - Fetch Subcollection Swift

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4, google-cloud-firestore

Converting from *Firebase* to *Firestore*

I have a database that looks like the following

[image]

Above is a Firebase node for entries in a photo album. The top level node is the ID of the Album (reference from another node) and scoped under each albumID there is a node (auto gen id) for each album entry (or picture). The expanded album has two album entries, the first of which is expanded.

**In Firebase - I could fetch the set of album entries (for a given album) by doing the following**

I could offset to the subnode and read from there.

```
    let dbKey = "byAlbum_entries"
    let ref  = Database.database().reference(fromURL: firebaseDB_URL)
    let albumEntryReference = ref.child( dbKey).child( forAlbum.objectid)

    albumEntryReference.observeSingleEvent(of : .value, with : { (snapshot) in ...
```

**In Firestore how do I retrieve that same set of album entries?**

is the correct syntax similar to below?  Can I get documents from a document and Firestore will know I am asking to look for a subcollection because I said getDocuments()?

```
    let dbKey = "byAlbum_entries"
    let ref  = Firestore.firestore()
    let albumEntryReference = ref.collection( dbKey).document( forAlbum.objectid)

    albumEntryReference.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        // no album entries found
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            // loop through album entries
        }
    }
```

}

**Part 2 ---  Data Model Good Practices with FIRESTORE**

It is better to restructure the data so that there is no subcollection and there is just a single collection where each entry includes both the albumID and the AlbumEntryID and I can just use a where clause to fetch only the album entries where albumID matches the one I am looking for? This would require an additional index whereas currently, in firebase, I can go directly to where I want to read and just read.

Even if restructuring does turn out to be better, I'd still appreciate help on the syntax to fetch all album entries for a given album as the database currently exists.